Integrating Neo4j GraphQL with Memgraph for traversals
I'd like to use Neo4j GraphQL to connect with a Memgraph database for a project that requires some simple graph traversals. I've heard that setting up a GraphQL client with Memgraph is possible, but the details of the implementation are a bit unclear to me.
Has anyone successfully configured Neo4j GraphQL with Memgraph? Could you give me tips on how to define the GraphQL schema, establish the necessary drivers, and set Memgraph as the database?

To set up a GraphQL client against a running Memgraph instance, you have to specify the GraphQL schema, set up the used drivers, and specify Memgraph as the used database. The process is described in the official docs at https://memgraph.com/docs/client-libraries/graphql.
